# Get all users in sharepoint farm and loop on them

Tags: powershell

I want a script who get all users on my sharepoint farm to save information.

Do you have a simple way to get all users and loop foreach on them to get

```
$userProfile["MainAffiliationSociety"].Value
```

And

```
$userProfile["AboutMe"].Value
```

Thanks !

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want to set user profile property to all users from your farm.

Microsoft provide ready made script for that.

[Update User Profile](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Update-User-Profile-8c5dc382)

Hope it will helpful to you.

And also visit [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?query=&f%5B1%5D.Value=&f%5B1%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=sharepoint&f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Text=SharePoint&ac=4) which will give most of the scripts related to sharepoint and it is authentic as it is given by Microsoft itself

Comment: Your script is just for one collection, no all farm...